# How to re update select box in java script

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project. So when ever i edit the names stored in an array, the select box value wont update o the new name.

The select box names where all appended with a java script loop and its in same array witht the names.

Can any one solve this problems.

Here is my code for generating and filling the select box.

```js
function displaycurrentName() {
  for (let g = 0; g < arrMain.length; g++) {
    const selectBx = document.createElement("option");
    selectBx.text = arrMain[g][1];
    selBox.options.add(selectBx)
    // renameMe.value = selBox.value;
    matchMe();
  }
}
```

It works only once and wont work again when I make edits...

Comment: Please create a runnable snippet in which we can experience your issue. Edit your question and look for the `<>` icon to create a snippet.

Comment: Please take the time to make it run properly as this is does not run. You're missing a lot of parts, like the HTML, the `matchme` function and the `arrMain`. Please include all necessary parts to make it run properly.

Comment: Javascript doesn't observe changes on its own. You need to make it observe changes you want to observe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.